# How to migrate data of Version 0.12.5 to cluster Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, migrate, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can the data in Version 0.12.5 of Apache IoTDB be directly migrated to the Cluster Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB? Do I need to export all tsfiles in Version 0.12.5, and then use `load` command to migrate data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to export tsfiles from Version 0.12.5, since tsfiles are all in the data directory. You can migrate the data with the following steps:

1. Stop the writing process to Version 0.12.5 of Apache IoTDB.
2. Execute `flush` command in `cli` tool in Version 0.12.5 of Apache IoTDB.
3. Execute `load` command on any DataNode in cluster Version 1.1.0 of Apache IoTDB. The specified folder for the `load` command should be the data folder of Version 0.12.5.